# How to go back to previous view from action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I had my back button on view controller two set to exit the view via dragging from action button to exit on view controller.

I'm trying to do it programatically now. I have

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"go back");
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Test");

    }];
    NSLog(@"are we back");
}
```

this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

didn't seem to do anything. but the current method of dismiss seems to work.

the problem is in my main view i had

```
-(IBAction) returnToMainView1:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
{
    NSLog(@"return to main view");
    self._mytopconsoleview=nil;
    self._mybottomconsoleview=nil;
    self.viewB=nil;
    [self animateRotation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}
```

and that is no longer called. How do i dismiss the current view controller and call a method on the main view like the one I have.

Mike

Comment: How are you presenting that view in the first place?  Is it presented modally, through a navigation controller, etc?

Comment: the view i'm in trying to get out of to main view had been brought  up ( and this is a recent change because both view changes now are on an action sheet, there are two scenes) self.viewB=vc;
    [self prepareForTab1Segue];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: thats not quite right on a technicality. view changes are programmatically on a toolbar. but on both action sheets and toolbars i have to create my buttons and their actions programmatically.

Comment: So just use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: or dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to get rid of the view (does this work for you?).  Then move the logic in the returnToMainView1 method to somewhere more appropriate like viewDidAppear.

Comment: is there any way to tell programmatically which view just gave up control or do you need to set up some system of variables to track that. like i could do viewb.destroyedMyself = true; and check that in viewdidappear.  when i set up return to main view with xcode originally i recall it was associated with the method returntomain as the method to call which gave me the idea if i added a third view i could have its own return function.

Comment: dismissViewController was working and visually it all looked good i just wanted to make sure i could clean up after. the main view has a telnet thread running and updates consoles in viewB, and i keep copies of the variables in the main view and i want them all going to nil when it's not up. Technically it may even work without that but seems sloppier.

Comment: also i wasn't sure if the main view controller called viewdidappear on return.  my thinking was the view never vanished it just had a view appear on top of it.  the viewb or top view really is destroyed but main view remains it seems in a consistent state the whole time. Should i assume viewdidappear is always called? I may not have anything there yet that would indicate it was called more than once. this is my first project i'm working with in ios and first with view methodology. And no it's not a professional project, it's just a learning project.

Comment: if you give an answer i'll check it as correct based on what you are saying which i think gives me a way to do what i want regardless of outcome of further responses.

Comment: This is actually working perfectly. I had viewdidload and viewdidappear confused. i only had code in viewdidload not in viewdidappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-iterating what I said in my comment - which apparently pushed you in the right path :)

Basically, you're looking to move the logic in the `returnToMainView1` method to viewDidAppear.  This is called whenever a view appears (as its name suggests) such as after dismissing a modal view controller.

Regarding the navigation view scheme, just dismiss based on how you presented.  If you used a modal view controller, use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` or if you used a navigation controller, use `popViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: thank you for your help. i'm semi learning ios from stackoverflow, google, and a bit of book learning.